# How to combine fat static libraries for use in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I got very confused when reading about static libraries and dynamic libraries and then finally about frameworks, Cocoa Touch Frameworks and Cocoa Touch Static Libraries.

The only thing I understood is that static libraries (frameworks?) are added at *compile* time, whereas dynamic libraries aren't; they're loaded dynamically during runtime.

#### Q:

I'd like to add several static libraries (they end with ".a", universal fat binaries, compiled for a bunch of iOS architectures such like armv7 and arm64) to my iOS application. Preferably, if possible, that'd be done by combining all of those libraries together (...to a framework?). 
I also want to write a Swift wrapper around those C libraries. This wrapper shall finally be used in my application. However, the wrapper shall not be part of my app, I want a separate project (again, a framework?) for that (can the libraries and the wrapper be combined together?).

What I'm currently trying to do is to write the Swift wrapper.
So I've started with a Cocoa Touch Framework (because I thought that would be the best idea), added the C libraries and headers (actually via a podspec, I don't think that matters though as I could also add them manually), added a bridging header (although some other users reported frameworks don't work with bridging headers, mine does build successfully). Is this the correct way to go?

The first article I read [was this one (called "Static and Dynamic Libraries and Frameworks in iOS")](http://www.vadimbulavin.com/static-dynamic-frameworks-and-libraries/).

Then, I read lots of articles on stackoverflow about how to compile static libraries, how libraries & frameworks are structured, that frameworks are really just a bundle of libraries and their headers (or so). 
I also feel like things have changed over the years at Apple, like they changed the names and possibilities (the Cocoa Touch Framework (is that a dynamic framework?) seems to have been introduced on the release of iOS 8 etc.), which made it even more difficult for me to understand how things work.
Don't get me wrong, I'm just saying this because I want to make clear that I have indeed done some research (quite a lot I think), but I really need some help to get everything right. Basically, I'm just looking for the next step I should take in order to import all those libraries to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two parts to this:

- Creating the framework Mach-O image
- Sorting out the headers

The first part should be relatively straightforward.  If you create a framework target and add a bunch of static libraries to it, the resulting framework will include all of those static libraries.

The only complication is Objective-C.  If any of your static libraries contain Objective-C code, the linker may end up stripping that out.  There’s a linker flag, -ObjC, that disables this.

Sorting out the headers is a bit more challenging.  Frameworks have their own view of how headers should be organised, and this generally doesn’t line up well with UNIX traditions (which is what you seem to have).  The critical question is how your client code uses these headers.  If the client code does stuff like:

```c
#include <lib_1/----1.h>
```

you have to preserve that layout on disk, and there’s no obvious way to do that when working with a framework.  OTOH, if you have control over the client code, and can change it to just do this:

```c
#include <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
```

you could create an umbrella header in your framework, have it include all of your public headers, and away you go.

*This answer was copied from the Apple Developer Forums.*